# Datatable search result add to cart enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have joined a script called jquery.mycart with datatable.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
var isEscape = false;
if ("key" in evt) {
    isEscape = (evt.key == "Enter" || evt.key == "Enter");
} else {
    isEscape = (evt.keyCode == 13);
}
if (isEscape) {

      table.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});


}
```

};

I have a problem that when we suppose we search for "Antalgina" when we press enter this search is added to the shopping cart. (look at the console).

Full code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaQJNg

Please how could I do it or give me some hint
I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working codePen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/mzaWoB).**

You could a simple jQuery event like :

```
$("document").on('onkeydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) {
       table.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
           console.log(value, index);
       });
    });
});
```